# jquery : not able to select table elements which are created dynamically by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, element, dynamically-generated

In html there is `<div id="tableContainer">`and to it I appended dynamically created a table

```
table = $("<table id="myTable" class='helpTable'>");
table.append("<tr id='1'><td>content<td></tr>");code
table.append("<tr id='2'><td>content<td></tr>"); code
$('#tableContainer').append(table);
```

Now I want to add event on table row like

```
 $("#myTable tr").on('click',function(event) {
alert("Hi"); });
```

Its not working, however following is case is working

```
$("#tableContainer").on('click',function(event) {
alert("Hi"); });
```

i.e. I can have event on static html tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is final solution using delegation

`$("#tableContainer").on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
    alert("Hi");});`

Its delegation from parent element to child.

Jquery is shorthand for Javascript, delegation for dynamic elements is not looking shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the table and the tr elements are created dynamically

```
$("#tableContainer").on('click', '#myTable tr', function (event) {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, actually `'click','#myTable tr'` didn't worked, but `'click','tr'` is working